# How to add a icon in the message for Ext.MesssageBox.alert

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have to add a currency symbol in the message text that has to be displayed in the messagebox. Is it possible using ExtJs 4.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Make a CSS class that has your image as the background, then set the `icon` of your `MessageBox` to be that class:

```
.my-message-box {
    background-image: url(images/bang.png);
}

Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Message title',
    msg: 'My Message',
    icon: 'my-message-box'
});
```

Comment: i assume that this adds the image to the background of the messagebox. I need an image to be added in the msg. Basically I need to give html content in the msg portion. Is that possible?

Comment: got the answer from this link : http://joeyjavas.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/using-html-in-an-extjs-message-box/